# Lowered written offer and many red flags, should I follow up on negotiation?

Tags: professionalism, communication, salary, job-offer, united-states

I’ve received an verbal offer from a small company offering X amount base, n% guaranteed bonus and discretionary bonus (as an industry standard structure). The whole package is merely 10% more than what I’m making now, so I called to negotiate with my HM, only to get lecture on what a growth opportunity it is (and it indeed would be imo). HM further persuaded me that the discretionary part will be the biggest chunk of pay as the industry has no “upper limit”.
I decided to say ok.
Then couple days later, this Monday, I saw the final written offer, which only offered X base, and 20% less on guaranteed, with no discretionary in first year. This will total out to be less than what I’m making now! So I sent back a negotiation email stating a raise and everything else as promised per verbal offer, but at a same time I think this gives me a really bad red flag on integrity of the company.

With the background, both HR and HM haven’t got back to my negotiation email and the offer deadline is this Friday. I would really appreciate any suggestions from everyone: should I call to confirm (I don’t really care if they rescind offer), or wait out (so not giving them an upper hand all of a sudden)?

Comment: I went through something similar recently. Honestly, your mortgage/grocery/utilities bills will not care about this "discretionary bonus". I would not use discretionary bonus as a decision maker in accepting a job. It's nice when it happens, but there should be no expectations that you will get it at all.

Comment: You verbally agreed to X with this company and they offered Y which is worse, not sure why you would even consider continuing any communication with this company.

Comment: @Catsunami thanks for the advice! But the fact is my base is high enough for me to enjoy a good life and in the industry bonus is what most people are after imho. So actually what pissed me off is I’ll only start getting it from second year given I already have experience.

Comment: @Mandosa *shrug* it depends. I'm in the SW industry, I know people who are after bonuses with lower base salaries. Some of them have same experience as me with lower pay but end up evening out after the bonus (I just have a higher base). It's personal preference I guess, but stability is also important to consider, as fun as bonuses are. Getting bonus from second year is exactly why I declined my offer a few months back; I just fail to see the motivation to jump ship to make LESS for a full year even with some hand-wavy promises in the future.

Comment: @Catsunami I guess in SW equity will pays out even better right? I’ve seen senior guys with 1mm equity 4yrs vesting etc. but in hedge fund circle even juniors would expect to get at least 50% base with unrealistic hope that one day we will all become PM and have million $ bonus haha. So if it’s a good fund it’ll be worth that wait, but for some place that’s so frugal to begin with, prob not a good idea.

Comment: What is an "HM"?

Comment: @nvoigt Hiring Manager

Comment: "no upper limit" - "great! And what's the lower limit?"

Comment: "discretionary bonus" means "We have no formal, measurable or achieveable bonus program and award them at our discretion, which is based on nebulous, unquantifiable metrics, so you'll probably never get one". - Companies that do the things you've listed in your question are not trustworthy and should not be trusted. If it were me, I'd pass on this opportunity.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the workplace. This question will likely be closed due to this reason : Questions asking for advice on a specific choice, such as what job to take or what skills to learn, are difficult to answer objectively and are rarely useful for anyone else. Instead of asking which decision to make, try asking how to make the decision, or for more specific details about one element of the decision. ([More information](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2693#2695)). Consider editing to ask whether these are red flags or if this is a normal behaviour.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would send them one, and only one, confirmation email, to confirm that they have received your counteroffer.  If they choose not to respond, then after the deadline you should send another email confirming you will not accept the offer.  You may want to explain why you will not accept the offer; I always like to provide feedback whenever I am causing a negative outcome for someone else, for their benefit.  I would mention:

1) Benefits too low
2) Deal was reneged on (causes lack of trust)
3) Ghosting you
4) Anything else you may care to mention not mentioned here

Comment: Hi Ertai87, thanks for the good advice, it sounds very reasonable and professional from my side!

Answer (score 21):

The phrase "No upper limit" is one of the biggest red flags there is, exceeded only by "growth opportunity."

**RUN, DON'T WALK FROM THIS ONE**

If they can't quantify something, it doesn't exist.  Multi-level-marketing (pyramid) schemes use this term all the time.

> There is no upper limit to what you can earn

or

> The growth potential is immense

That's all nonsense.  Run from it.  It is just code for "We have no money"

Comment: Hahaha I enjoyed this answer! In fact I might steal your line to leave a Glassdoor review. But what I don’t understand is, they’re already paying me a six digit salary, why still so cheap on the side?

Comment: @Mandosa: The presence of money does not directly correlate to good business sense. People can get money from a lot of places, but that doesn't meant that they won't still try to be cheap. Most likely, someone is looking for a means to cut costs/corners, and that means low-balling you. If a person with your skillset typically costs X, and they can con you into doing it for X-Y, then they've still saved (short term) money. That's likely the logic they're following.

Answer (score 13):

To quote another known for their *aggressive* negotiations..

> I am altering the deal. Pray I don't alter it any further.

Joking aside - you came to what you thought was an agreed package that was acceptable to you, now they have lowered that package without consulting you. Now they are ignoring your response indicating that you will only accept the original deal. Why is joining this company still even on the table at this point?